# Display value inside input

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

[image]

I have designed my form till here. Now I further want to show the amount of the particular row over there in the row in Amounts column.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="itemamt" readonly value="{{itemrow.get('itemqty').value * itemrow.get('itemrate').value}}">
```

Comment: Sure @AJT_82 I'll edit my post and show you how my this.thisinvoiceno look like. Invoice no is correctly being displayed.

Comment: Please tell @AJT_82 how to show the multiplication value of qty and rate of that particular row in Amount column

Comment: @AJT_82 It's not empty. I am returning data to thisinvoiceno from firebase using angularfire2. It's working properly after your solution.

Comment: @AJT_82 You can see in the image I have attached the invoiceno is autofilled

Comment: @AJT_82 Just leave invoiceno empty

Comment: What I really want is to show the Amount of that particular row by calculating it form qty and rate entered by user... @AJT_82

Comment: Aah, now I understand what you mean. Can't answer you off the bat right now, as this is something I have not done with reactive forms. I'd need to try it out myself. But can say that much that it needs to be a formcontrol and somehow assign the value from `itemqty` multiplicated with `itemrate` naturally :)

Comment: @yurzui Plunk has already been created The link to plunk is http://embed.plnkr.co/1292b4RgQRsdcwba5hQ4/

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/1oOlqnvSIvUUN1rMkkzg?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui just checkout this plunk https://embed.plnkr.co/WYlckAFJjk3GmR5eRaSn/

Comment: I want to have it as a FormControl @AZT_82

Comment: Replace `[value]` with `[ngModel]` and respect life outside SO :) https://plnkr.co/edit/yWbbZuHyWbnGH5Wpgqwh?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui Ah, the obvious solution! I think I have a brain dysfunction :D Somehow I have just removed `ngModel` from my brain (when paired with model driven form), so I over complicated my (horrible) deleted answer. Great one, thanks from me as well for the solution, opened up my eyes a bit :)

Comment: @yurzui Can you please tell me that how to finally sum itemamt of all rows in itemRows

Comment: @ClimbTree Don't worry, all is good! :) Since I'm here, I could try and explain what's happening in yurzui's code: so the ngModel is: `[ngModel]="itemrow.get('itemqty').value * itemrow.get('itemrate').value"`. `itemrow` refers to that particular row (since you are iterating the formcontrols of this formarray with `let itemrow of ....`). `get(itemqty).value` refers to the formcontrol `itemqty` on that row and we extract the value of that formcontrol with the prefix `value`. The same goes with the `itemrow.get('itemrate').value`. More clear now? :)

Answer (score 0):

To pass FormControll Value inside FormArray you can do something like this with angular,

```
form = new FormGroup({
     name: new FormControl('Name'),
     username: new FormArray([
                  new FormControl("value"),
                  {firstName:"Andrew", lastName:"Donald"},
                  {firstName:"Charles", lastName:"Jackson"}
                ])
   });
```

Hope this might be helpfull for you.

Comment: If you might have checked out plunkr I hae already patched Values for formControls. I wanted to ask if I want to get values entered by user at a particular time and show those values in amount column